# time trigger + multiple events in Pubsub

Tags: google-cloud-composer

I am ingesting 2 different datasets on GCS. Lets say I write a event e1 and event e2 respectively in pubsub which happens at a different times.

I want to start a job and 9 AM and check when both events e1 and e2 have happened for that particular day (After 9 AM) then i kick a process to generate another dataset from these 2 datasets.

Is Cloud composer right to build this kind of requirement. If yes, then please provide some guidance how it can be done

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Composer (and Airflow) should be right for this use case.

You can create a DAG with a daily `schedule_interval` that starts at 9 am. Use a [PubsubSensor](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/sensors/pubsub_sensor.py) per event (`s1` and `s2`). Assuming the process to generate another dataset is an operator, you could then ensure that `generate_dataset` occurs by setting dependencies:

```
s1 >> generate_dataset
s2 >> generate_dataset
```